# My jQuery callback is failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I created a plug-in to display a Metro MessageBar and it works great.  I was asked to support `callbacks` and added some code to the `fadeIn` functionality for this purpose.

**For some reason, the `callback` shows as a valid `function`, but doesn't call?**

**HERE IS THE CONSOLE MESSAGE I AM GETTING:**

```
this.trigger is not a function
```

...any help is appreciated.

**THIS IS HOW TO USE THE PLUG-IN:**

```
this.showSubmitMessage = function () {
    var options = {
        message: "This is a test.",
        messageType: "information"
        };

    // self.btnSubmit.click IS a valid function!!!  Use your own if you want.
    nalco.es.rk.globals.messageBarManager.display(options, self.btnSubmit.click);
};
```

**THIS IS THE OFFENDING AREA-OF-CODE IN THE PLUG-IN:**

```
this.fadeIn = function (element, callback) {
element.prependTo(self.container).centerToScrollTop().fadeIn(self.globals.fadeDuration, function() {
       if (callback != null)
           if ($.isFunction(callback))
               setTimeout(function () {
                   callback();
                }, self.globals.callbackDuration);
    });
};
```

**THIS IS THE ENTIRE USER-CONTROL PLUG-IN:**
Please notice the code for the file-dependency "jquery.Extensions.js" is at the bottom of this posting.

```
    <script src="Scripts/jQuery/Core/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jQuery/Core/jquery.tmpl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/jQuery/jquery.Extensions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .messageBar { background-color: #DDDDDD; color: #666666; display: none; left: 0; padding: 15px; position: absolute; top: 0; width: 932px; z-index: 1000; }
    .messageBar .content { width: 100%; }
    .messageBar .content td.image { width: 70px; }
    .messageBar .content td.button { width: 60px; }
    .messageBar .button { margin-top: 0px; }

    .messageBar .content .icon { background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 31px; overflow: hidden; width: 31px; }
    .messageBar .content .message {  }
    .messageBar .content .image { background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 10px; overflow: hidden; width: 70px; }

    .messageBar.error { background-color: #FFBABA; color: #D8000C; }
    .messageBar.information { background-color: #99CCFF; color: #00529B; }
    .messageBar.success { background-color: #DFF2BF; color: #4F8A10; }
    .messageBar.warning { background-color: #FEEFB3; color: #9F6000; }

    .messageBar.error .content .icon { background-image: url('/_layouts/images/error.png'); }
    .messageBar.information .content .icon { background-image: url('/_layouts/images/info.png'); }
    .messageBar.success .content .icon { background-image: url('/_layouts/images/success.png'); }
    .messageBar.warning .content .icon { background-image: url('/_layouts/images/warning.png'); }
</style>

<script id="template-messageBar" type="text/html">
    <div class="messageBar">
        <table class="content">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="button">
                        <input type="button" value="Close" class="button metroButton" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</script>

<script id="template-messageBar-icon" type="text/html">
    <div class="icon">
    </div>
</script>

<script id="template-messageBar-message" type="text/html">
    <div class="message">
        ${Message}
    </div>
</script>

<script id="template-messageBar-image" type="text/html">
    <div class="image">
    </div>
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        ;nalco.es.rk.source.MessageBarManager = (function ($) {
            var publicInstances = {};

            publicInstances.Controller = Controller;
            function Controller(options) {

                var self = this;

                this.messageTypes = { error: "error", information: "information", normal: null, success: "success", warning: "warning" };
                this.globals = {
                    callbackDuration: 2000,
                    fadeDuration: 700,
                    workingImageUrl: "url('/_layouts/images/Nalco.ES.SharePoint.UI/metro-ajax-loader-blue.gif')"
                };
                this.defaults = {
                    message: "",
                    messageType: self.messageTypes.normal,
                    showIcon: false,
                    showWorkingImage: false
                };

                this.container = $('body');

                this.templateMessageBarId = '#template-messageBar';
                this.templateMessageBarIconId = '#template-messageBar-icon';
                this.templateMessageBarMessageId = '#template-messageBar-message';
                this.templateMessageBarImageId = '#template-messageBar-image';

                this.selectors = { content: '.content', closeButton: '.button', root: '.messageBar' };

                this.initialize = function () {
                    self.display(options);
                };
                this.display = function (options, callback) {

                    var empty = {};
                    var settings = $.extend(empty, self.defaults, $.isPlainObject(options) ? options : empty);

                    if (settings.messageType != null)
                        if (settings.messageType.length == 0)
                            settings.messageType = self.messageTypes.normal;

                    if (settings.message.length == 0)
                        return;

                    var eleMessageBar = $(self.templateMessageBarId).tmpl(empty);
                    var eleContent = $(self.selectors.content, eleMessageBar);
                    var eleCellOne = $('td:eq(0)', eleContent);
                    var eleCellTwo = $('td:eq(1)', eleContent);
                    var eleCellThree = $('td:eq(2)', eleContent);

                    var eleMessage = $(self.templateMessageBarMessageId).tmpl({ Message: settings.message });
                    var btnClose = $(self.selectors.closeButton, eleMessageBar);

                    if (settings.messageType != self.messageTypes.normal) {
                        eleMessageBar.addClass(settings.messageType);

                        if (settings.showIcon) {
                            var eleIcon = $(self.templateMessageBarIconId).tmpl(empty);
                            eleCellOne.css('width', '31px');
                            eleIcon.appendTo(eleCellOne);
                        }
                    }

                    eleMessage.appendTo(eleCellTwo);
                    btnClose.click(function () {
                        eleMessageBar.fadeOut(self.globals.fadeDuration, function () {
                            eleMessageBar.remove();
                        });
                    });

                    if (settings.showWorkingImage) {
                        var eleImage = $(self.templateMessageBarImageId).tmpl(empty);
                        eleCellThree.addClass('image');
                        eleImage.css('background-image', self.globals.workingImageUrl);
                        eleImage.appendTo(eleCellThree);
                    }

                    var elePreviousMessage = $(self.selectors.root, self.container);
                    if (elePreviousMessage.length > 0) {
                        btnClose = $(self.selectors.closeButton, elePreviousMessage);
                        btnClose.click();
                        setTimeout(function () { self.fadeIn(eleMessageBar, callback); }, self.globals.fadeDuration);
                    }
                    else
                        self.fadeIn(eleMessageBar, callback);
                };
                this.fadeIn = function (element, callback) {
                    element.prependTo(self.container).centerToScrollTop().fadeIn(self.globals.fadeDuration, function() {
                        if (callback != null)
                            if ($.isFunction(callback))
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                     callback();
                                }, self.globals.callbackDuration);
                    });
                };

                self.initialize();
            };

            return publicInstances;
        })(jQuery);

        function initializeMessageBarManager() {
            nalco.es.rk.globals.messageBarManager = new nalco.es.rk.source.MessageBarManager.Controller();
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            initializeMessageBarManager();

            if (typeof (Sys) != "undefined")
                Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(initializeMessageBarManager);
        });
    </script>
```

**THIS IS THE EXTENSIONS DEPENDENCY LISTED IN THE FILES ABOVE:**

```
// **********************
// .centerToScrollTop
// Use -
// Centers an ELEMENT to the window's scrollTop.
//
// Example -
// $('.myElement').centerToScrollTop();
// **********************
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        centerToScrollTop: function (options) {
            return this.each(function () {
                var element = $(this);
                var container = $(window);
                var scrollTop = container.scrollTop();
                var buffer = 30;
                var top = scrollTop + buffer;
                var left = (container.width() - element.outerWidth()) / 2 + container.scrollLeft();

                element.css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top': top, 'left': left });

                return element;
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Your 'Entire code' bit passes in `callback`, whereas your offending code bit uses `self.callback()`. Which one is it?? There's no `this.callback = function() {}`

Comment: Updated...and corrected.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird cos there isn't even `this.trigger` in your code? lol. Is `this.showSubmitMessage` in the `Controller()` function as well? All I can think is that if its not there, `self` probably wouldn't work inside `this.showSubmitMessage`? If it is there... Can you get the callback to run in any part in `this.display` (if you just put the `callback()` function anywhere in there to test)

Comment: There is way too much code here to sift through, but not enough to come up with a full example.  Please post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the issue.  Even better would be to pare away any unnecessary code - ie, code that is irrelevant to the specific problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

This type of error occurs usually if you forgot to include some files like jquery-ui.min.js etc. Check carefully if you add all the necessary references.